# Regex expression to search a word followed by any sign of a certain set

Tags: php, regex

Ik want to write a regex expression to check strings for words followed by a `?,:,!` but I tried so many things and nothing seems to work properly.. 
The best I came up with is: `\\b([a-zA-Z]*)([\:]|[\?])\`

The test phrase? is something: like this! to test whether everything? works.

I am writing a function that come's from the example sentence above to the following result:

```
array(
[0] => phrase,
[1] => array(
             [0] => something, 
             [1] => like this,
[2] => everything
)
```

Comment: As this is your fifth question asked here, I would start to accept answers (the check mark to the left of the answer just beneath the votes) as many users won't help you when they see you don't accept the given answers to your question. But remember: always accept the answer that helped you the most! If none of the answers solved your problem, then it's perfectly valid to not accept an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You might try this instead:

```
\b\w+\b(?=[!:?])
```

This will produce the following result for your test sentence:

```
'phrase', 'something', 'this', 'everything'
```

You have an initial word boundary (`\b`), but you do not complete the word before looking for a `!`, `:`, or `?`. These punctuation marks will not match within a given word.

Further, `[!:?]` will by default just match any one of those three punctuation marks, so you don't need an or (`|`).

If you are looking to match every full phrase/sentence before those three punctuation marks, you could try a regular expression like this:

```
\w[\w\s]+?(?=[!:?])
```

This would give you:

```
'The test phrase', 'is something', 'like this', 'to test whether everything'
```

Comment: Ok you helped me already enormously!
Although I have one more question: 

Is it possible to create a regex that combines the two results you gave. I mean, a regex that returns just the single word if the words has a ? behind it and that returns several words when there is a word with a ':'? When there is a word with a ':', I want to caputure that word and every following word until the next !

I could write a function with 2 regex expressions and some actions but I was wondering whether this could be done in one regex.

Comment: @user3156386 So do you mean you just want (1) every word that precedes a question mark and (2) every phrase/sentence between a colon and an exclamation point?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for

```
(\w+)[?!:]
```

if you just want to make sure a word is followed by one of `?!:`. No need for a lookahead, checks for word boundaries or other things (always remember: keep it simple and stupid!).

---

Regarding your comment on [@275365s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074728/1807643):

> a regex that returns just the single word if the words has a ? behind it and that returns several words when there is a word with a ':'? When there is a word with a ':', I want to caputure that word and every following word until the next !

This is perfectly possible:

```
(\w+)\?|(\w+):\s?(.+?)!
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m-lUKG49hqEb4K8M)
[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dW0hB3)

Again: keep it simple and stupid, but note that **this will fail** if there are nested `:?!` inside a `:abc!` block!
For example the sentence `i: will? fail!` won't give you the single `will`, it will give you `i` and `will? fail`.

Explanation:

```
  (\w+)\?   #every word which is followed by a ?
|           #OR
  (\w+)    #every word
  :         #which is followed by a : 
  \s?       #and an optional whitespace
  (.+?)     #every character
  !         #until a ! is encountered
```